# How to compute group homology of Iwasawa algebra

Tags: group-cohomology, iwasawa-theory

Let $G$ be a $p$-adic Lie group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$. What is $H_1(H,\Lambda(G))$, where $\Lambda(G)$ is the Iwasawa algebra of $G$ over $\mathbb Z_p$?

If it simplies the question, we may assume $G$ is commutative. Or maybe even just $\mathbb Z_p^d$. I don't know how to do it even for this simple case.

I just realize that I have very few tools to compute group homology, unlike its cohomology cousins. A very embarrassing question: how do you compute group homology in general?